# Prediction results are the same for each row of input

Tags: python, machine-learning

## Here is the code:

```
enter code here 
unseen_data = read_csv('New_data_covid19_Delhi.csv', header=0, delimiter=';')
unseen_data = unseen_data.drop('Date', axis=1)
unseen_array = unseen_data.values
model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=7)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted = model.predict(unseen_array)
for i in range(len(unseen_array)):
    print('Unseen=%d, Predicted=%d' % (unseen_array[i], predicted[i]))***


# Results of prediction:

Unseen=4459048, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=4576771, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=4657025, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=4788869, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=4790426, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=4934414, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=5066853, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=5142295, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=5268862, Predicted=1324339
Unseen=5273549, Predicted=1324339
```

Questions: what is possible reason the Predicted are always the same? Could it be correct?
I'm really fresh for ML. Please, help.

Comment: have you checked your y_train values. Also could it be the shape of your unseen_array?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked: y_train.shape: (107,) type: ndarray; unseen_array.shape: (10, 1), type: ndarray. What do you think? Thank you.